# Access rights denied to delete files for streamlit app python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, streamlit

I obtain the followin error:

```
 [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Users\\ludov\\Bureau\\eco-tech-h2gam\\forecast\\fr\\CO_concentration-2023-12-29.gif'
Failed to delete C:\Users\ludov\Bureau\eco-tech-h2gam\forecast\fr\NO2_concentration-2023-12-29.gif. Reason: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Users\\ludov\\Bureau\\eco-tech-h2gam\\forecast\\fr\\NO2_concentration-2023-12-29.gif'
Failed to delete C:\Users\ludov\Bureau\eco-tech-h2gam\forecast\fr\O3_concentration-2023-12-29.gif. Reason: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Users\\ludov\\Bureau\\eco-tech-h2gam\\forecast\\fr\\O3_concentration-2023-12-29.gif'
Failed to delete C:\Users\ludov\Bureau\eco-tech-h2gam\forecast\fr\PM10_concentration-2023-12-29.gif. Reason: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Users\\ludov\\Bureau\\eco-tech-h2gam\\forecast\\fr\\PM10_concentration-2023-12-29.gif'
Failed to delete C:\Users\ludov\Bureau\eco-tech-h2gam\forecast\fr\PM2.5_concentration-2023-12-29.gif. Reason: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Users\\ludov\\Bureau\\eco-tech-h2gam\\forecast\\fr\\PM2.5_concentration-2023-12-29.gif'
Failed to delete C:\Users\ludov\Bureau\eco-tech-h2gam\forecast\fr\SO2_concentration-2023-12-29.gif. Reason: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Users\\ludov\\Bureau\\eco-tech-h2gam\\forecast\\fr\\SO2_concentration-2023-12-29.gif'
```

When trying to delete files in a subprocess line 39 within my app.py I run by doing streamlit run app.py:

```
import streamlit as st
import base64
import os, glob
import platform
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date


class app():

    def __init__(self, sys, work_dir):
        self.sys = sys
        self.work_dir = work_dir   
        
    def display_gifs(self):
        if self.sys == "Windows":
            mypath = self.work_dir + "\\forecast\\fr\\"
        else:
            mypath = self.work_dir + "/forecast/fr/" 
        os.chdir(mypath)
        fileslist = []
        for file in glob.glob("*.gif"):
            print(file)
            fileslist.append(file)

        dateoffile = pd.to_datetime(fileslist[0].split("_concentration-")[1].split(".")[0],dayfirst = False)
        print(pd.Timestamp(date.today())  - dateoffile)
        if(pd.Timestamp(date.today())  - dateoffile > pd.Timedelta("1 Days")):
            print(pd.Timestamp(date.today())  - dateoffile)
            print("IN HERE")
            if self.sys == "Windows":
                subprocess.run(["python", self.work_dir + "\\DownloadCAMSforecast.py"])
                subprocess.run(["python", self.work_dir + "\\maps.py"])
            else:
                subprocess.run(["python", self.work_dir + "/DownloadCAMSforecast.py"])
                subprocess.run(["python", self.work_dir + "/maps.py"])

        file_1 = open(mypath + fileslist[0], "rb")
        contents = file_1.read()
        data_url1 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_1.close()

        file_2 = open(mypath + fileslist[1], "rb")
        contents = file_2.read()
        data_url2 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_2.close()

        file_3 = open(mypath + fileslist[2], "rb")
        contents = file_3.read()
        data_url3 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_3.close()

        # HTML code to display gifs side by side
        html_code1 = f"""
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url1}" alt="GIF 1" style="width: 28%;" loop = True>
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url2}" alt="GIF 2" style="width: 28%;" loop = True>
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url3}" alt="GIF 3" style="width: 28%;" loop = True>
            </div>
        """

        file_4 = open(mypath + fileslist[3], "rb")
        contents = file_4.read()
        data_url4 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_4.close()

        file_5 = open(mypath + fileslist[4], "rb")
        contents = file_5.read()
        data_url5 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_5.close()

        file_6 = open(mypath + fileslist[5], "rb")
        contents = file_6.read()
        data_url6 = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")
        file_6.close()

        # HTML code to display gifs side by side
        html_code2 = f"""
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url4}" alt="GIF 4" style="width: 28%;" loop = True>
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url5}" alt="GIF 5" style="width: 28%;" loop>
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{data_url6}" alt="GIF 6" style="width: 28%;" loop>
            </div>
        """
        
        # Display the HTML code
        st.markdown(html_code1, unsafe_allow_html=True)
        st.markdown(html_code2, unsafe_allow_html=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp = app(platform.system(), os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) )
    MyApp.display_gifs()
```

The subprocess' delete operations work successfully if I use python maps.py instead of running the subprocess from the streamlit app. And they don't work even if I run streamlit as an administrator within the windows cmd shell...

Any ideas?

Please find the part that deletes the file in maps.py below:

```
print('Create gif ...', flush=True, end='')
        if sys == "Windows":
            gifPath = work_dir + "\\forecast\\fr\\"
        else:
            gifPath = work_dir + "/forecast/fr/"

        folder = gifPath
        for filename in os.listdir(folder):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            try:
                if os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.islink(file_path):
                    os.unlink(file_path)
                elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
                    shutil.rmtree(file_path)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Failed to delete %s. Reason: %s' % (file_path, e))
```

Comment: It seems like the subprocess itself doesn't have permission to delete those files

Comment: For a quick and dirty fix, try adding `shell=True` to your `subprocess.run` calls.

Comment: subprocess.run(["python", self.work_dir + "\\maps.py"],shell=True) gives the exact same errors

Comment: This changes nothing either: subprocess.run(["python", self.work_dir + "\\maps.py", "shell=True"])

Comment: Do you have the files open in another program, or even just have the folder open in file explorer?